# Partial Class not recognizing "using customnamespace" or any methods affiliated with a non-partial class on Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I'm setting up a tool for a randomized generator for some friends. I'm working with Windows Forms for the first time and am having trouble with the Button_Click event handler. The problem is this:

The project is set up with project.scripts.subset stylization. Form1.cs is a partial class, and I'm working within the confines of the event handlers. Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) Does not seem to recognize the methods of other classes, despite having the proper using set up. I'm trying to determine if there's a means of fixing this, or determining what I am doing wrong.

Unfortunately, I haven't tried too much due to inexperience in using buttons. Originally, I attempted to make the handlers in the Form1.Designer.cs and switched when I realized pressing the buttons in the [Design] generates a class to handle that information for you.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using project.code.location1;

namespace project
{
 partial class Form1: Form
 {
  public Form1()
  {
...
  }
   void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    GenerateA();
   }
...
 }
}

namespace project.code.location1
{
 class foo
 {
  public void GenerateA()
  {
...
  }
 }
}
```

The expected result is for GenerateA() in class Foo to be usable by the event handler of Button1_Click(), but for some reason it's continually throwing an error message stating that GenerateA() does not exist. In a Windows Application, it does not throw this error message in the system when the same function is called elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using GenerateA() it needs to be a static method in a static class and you need to use either foo.GenerareA() or add foo to your using clause.